When using Apple M CPU I encounter this error "Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file"
This is not a question about what multidex is!
I am using a Macbook with M3 CPU. I have a modular project which has multidex enabled in its main module ("app" module). My problem is that when I "rebuild" my project in Android Studio I encounter this error, the error is being displayed for some of my modules and when I enable multidex in those modules the error goes away:
Execution failed for task ':feature:mergeDexDebugAndroidTest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

However, When I click "run", the app is built and installed successfully on a device.
The mentioned error does not show up on windows os and is only happening on Apple Sillicon (M) CPU.
What can be the reason for this weird error?

What is the minSDK of your project?

@MorrisonChang It is minSdkVersion = 19

minSDK=19 is KitKat which was released in 2013, Google Play Services ended support for API 19 & API 20 last year: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/07/google-play-services-discontinuing-updates-for-kitkat.html  Upon raising the minSDK level, you should be able to remove multidex flags: https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#mdex-gradle At a guess Google didn't test such new Mac hardware with such a old build requirement.
